# Card number validation inconsistent error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am producing a page that takes in a set of card details as a **form**. The fields need to be validated manually (without HTML 5) using **JavaScript**. The one problem I am having is with the **16 digit card number** field.

- **123456789012345r** returns *no error* message (in the if statement below)
- **1234567rt0123456** returns *no error* message
- **1234rt7890123456** returns *no error* message
- **1234dv7890123456** returns *no error* message
- **rt34567890123456** returns *an error* message

I can't figure out why I am getting this inconsistant failier to validate. What is the problem with my code? 
Thanks.

### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="submitDetails()">
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" style="left:200px;position: absolute;"><br />
        <input type="text" id="cardNo" placeholder="Card Number" style="left:200px;position: absolute;"><br />
        <input type="text" id="expMonth" placeholder="MM" style="left:200px;position: absolute;">
        <input type="text" id="expYear" placeholder="YYYY" style="left:350px;position: absolute;"><br />
        <input type="text" id="secCode" placeholder="Security Code" style="left:200px;position: absolute;"><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Details" style="left:200px;position: absolute;">
    </form>
```

### JavaScript

```
 var cardNo = document.getElementById('cardNo').value;

 if ((cardNo.toString().length != 16) || (isNaN(parseInt(cardNo)))){
            errorMsg += "\n\u2022 Enter a Card Number of 16 digits.\n"
 }
```

Comment: Not all credit card systems use 16-digit card numbers, fyi.

Comment: Kudos for trying to build it yourself - too few people do that these day. But, Googling `javascript credit card validation` will give you ready-made tools. Just FYI.

Comment: Learn what parseInt does....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseInt()` function parses an integer from the front of the string you give it. When it encounters something that's not part of a number, it stops and returns the value it's seen so far. Only if the string starts with something that cannot be interpreted as numeric will it return `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.